# Data structure to GetMean in O(log n) time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, avl-tree

I need ideas for designing a data structure that does **insert**, **delete** and **getmean**(a,b)  all in 
**O(log n)** time. **getmean**(a,b) is the arithmetic mean of all number x in [a,b)

**My Thoughts** - 
Generally, insert and delete operations could be done in O(log n) time if we store data in
Balanced Search Trees like AVL Trees. But to solve getmean(a,b) in O(log n) time we need to store
some additional information. For calculating mean we could do the following: 
recursively do an in-depth traversal. If the current element <a then we don't need to traverse
the left sub-tree. If current element > b then we don't need to traverse the right-subtree.
If the current element is between a and b then we include that element in our set. 
**But this approach needs some modification**. For consider the case where all the elements in the
collection are in [a,b). Then this method will traverse all the items in the collection.
Resulting in O(n) operation.

Comment: If you keep the sum of the elments of each subtree in the root of that subtree, then you can walk down in O(log n) at the borders of your interval and correct for inside/outside membership.

Answer (score 0):

Have every node in the tree store a count and sum of the elements below it.

You can then calculate the count and sum of any range in log(n) steps.  From which you can calculate the mean.

The trick for calculating those stats in a range is that if I am on a node that I know is entirely within my range, then I can look at its stats and don't have to visit the range.  Which means that I just have to explore the edge of the range.  Assuming a tree, here is untested Python that you can treat as pseudocode.

```
def find_min (node):
    if node.left is not None:
        return find_min(node.left)
    else:
        return node.value

def find_max (node):
    if node.right is not None:
        return find_min(node.right)
    else:
        return node.value

def find_count_sum_range(node, start, end, lower=None, upper=None):
    # Calculate bounds if not found.
    if lower is None:
        lower = find_min(node)

    if upper is None:
        upper = find_min(node)

    # Shortcut if this node is entirely in the range.
    if start <= lower and upper < end:
        return (node.count, node.sum)

    # Initialize
    count_left = sum_left = 0
    count_this = sum_this = 0
    count_right = sum_right = 0

    # Do we find range to the left?
    if start <= node.value and node.left is not None:
        (count_left, sum_left) = find_count_sum_range(
            node.left, start, end, lower, node.value)

    # Do we find range to the right?
    if node.value < end and node.right is not None:
        (count_left, sum_left) = find_count_sum_range(
            node.left, start, end, node.value, upper)

    # Is this node in range?
    if start <= node.value and node.value < end:
        (count_this, sum_this) = (1, node.value)

    # Add up our answer
    return (
        count_left + count_this + count_right,
        sum_left + sum_this + sum_right
    )
```

I personally would find it easier to implement with a [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) than an AVL tree, but that's because I'm lazy and don't want to think through the tree operations.  But even there the trick remains the same - whenever you can just read off the count and sum of a range, don't visit nodes in that range.

Comment: Could you elaborate that part. How sum of any any range can be calculated in log(n) steps. I am unable to see how that will work.

Comment: @ishita I added an explanation.  The trick is that you do a bunch of work to avoid visiting chunks of the tree that you know are in your range.

Comment: # Do we find range to the right?
    if node.value < end and node.right is not None:
        (count_left, sum_left) = find_count_sum_range(
            node.left, start, end, node.value, upper)   this should be :                                    ``-----------------------------------`  # Do we find range to the right?
    if node.value < end and node.right is not None:
        (count_right, sum_right) = find_count_sum_range(
            node.right, start, end, node.value, upper)         `                  Is that correct ?  It does look log(n) time. But I will try proving it formally

Comment: Also I think when we insert an element. Since we say are using AVL trees to make it balanced. when rotations will be performed. How will we maintain the property - `storing the count and sum of elements below this`. Will that be possible to preserve ?

Comment: @ishita That's the part about trees that would make me want to do a skip list.  But in a left or right rotation, the node moved down now has count 1 and sum its value, and the node moved up has its count increased by 1 and sum increased by the value moved down.  In a left-right and a right-left rotation you do that two times with different nodes.

Comment: I just had a look at skip list. So skip list will basically store the elements in sorted order. It's like I could store the sorted items in an array and so binary search could yield insertion, deletion and mean in O(log n) time. But since arrays are indexed that's where the problem lies and so we can user skip-list to remove that problem. In using skip list how will the mean be stored to make it run in O(log n)

Comment: I think I have a counter-example to - `runtime is O(log n)`. Check this - [https://easyupload.io/3sbk3m](https://easyupload.io/3sbk3m) . This is the case where the left side of tree just contains one element which is not in the range. In such a case we end up traversing the whole tree

Comment: @ishita I can't see your image.  But if the tree is balanced you can't be forced to traverse the whole tree.  Just a maximum of 6 nodes per level.  2 at the edges when looking for the min/max, 2 whose children include the boundary and 2 internal nodes that you don't descend farther in.  Since there are `O(log(n))` levels, that's a total of `O(log(n))` nodes to visit.

Comment: https://ibb.co/q7wJHxf - This shows the image well. It's not balanced, but you could add more nodes easily to make it balanced

Comment: @ishita By the time that you add enough nodes to make it balanced `n` will have become large enough that the work is `O(log(n))`.

Comment: Could you provide some insight into, proving this theoretically that the runtime will be O(log(n)) always

Comment: As per what I see if there is a similar tree like the one I posted, then it will traverse the whole left path and calling `find_min() for each node`. As each `find_min()` takes O(log n) time the total time complexity will be much more than that

Comment: @ishita An AVL tree has at most `O(log(n))` levels.  (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree to verify.)  We visit at most 6 nodes per level.  At each node we do a `O(1)` calculation.  Therefore we do only `O(log(n))` work.  QED.

Comment: Can something similar be done if we want to calculate standard deviation also in O(log n) time ?